# Why does my toString() print this?

Tags: tostring

```
public static void main(String args[]){
Person p = new Person();

System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

This is where i call toString on the class.
The class is:
   public class Person {

```
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private int age;
private int salary;

public void setFN(String NewName)
{FirstName = NewName;}

public void setLN(String NewName)
{LastName = NewName;}

public void setAge(int NewAge)
{age = NewAge;}

public void setSalary(int NewSalary)
{salary = NewSalary;}

public String getFN()
{return FirstName;}

public String getLN()
{return LastName;}

public int getAge()
{return age;}

public int getSalary()
{return salary;}
```

}
And it prints this:

```
Person@7852e922
```

I would like to know why it prints this and what it is. My teacher gave me this assignment but I can't find anything on google or any other place.

Comment: That's the default output.  What do you expect it to print?

Comment: I don't expect it to print anything, I just wanna understand why it prints that! like does it have a meaning or something? all the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're seeing comes from the Java default `toString` method:

> **public String toString()**
>
> Returns a string representation of the
> object. In general, the toString method returns a string that
> "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but
> informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is
> recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString
> method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the
> class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@',
> and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
> object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
> value of:
>
> **getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())**
>
> Returns: a string representation of the object.

[For more information about this take a look at the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-tostring-method

`toString()` default output is:

**Class Name** + **@** + **the hex version of the object’s hash code** concatenated into a string.

The default hash code method in Object is typically implemented by converting the memory address of the object into an integer.